# Deleting part of an XML using PL/SQL

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

I am trying to delete the end part of a xml file and save it into a variable.

The xml has something similar to this structure:

```
<what_to_delete>
    <Body_of_what_to_Delete>
        several strings of characters i want to delete
        spreaded across several lines.
    </Body_of_what_to_Delete>
</what_to_delete>
```

I want to know if there exists a suitable function in PL/SQL that implements this request.

Something like delete from '<what_to_delete>' to '</what_to_delete>':

```
DELETE_FROM(file_to_trim, '<what_to_delete>', '</what_to_delete>');
```

This is supposed to be in several xml files and not just in one. Also, what I want to delete varies widely from file to file, so a "delete from '' up to ''" would be the most suitable way.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DELETEXML.

```
UPDATE your_table
  SET your_col = deleteXML(your_col, '//what_to_delete');
```

Comment: Sorry Mr Thomas Kirchhoff, i forgot to mention this is supposed to be in several xml files and not just in one. Also, what i want to delete varies widely to file, so a "delete from <tag> up to </tag>" would be the most suitable way. Is there anything we can use in this case?
Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @DiogoBasilio The function deletes everything from an opening <tag> to a closing </tag>, that is, an entire node. No matter what is in between.

If different nodes are to be deleted, then you must apply the function accordingly only to the desired result set. Otherwise, nothing happens even if the node does not exist in the XML. The update is only a simple example.